# Pi Pico shorted after working fine

Tags: power-supply, short-circuit, midi, raspberry-pi-pico

After working for a couple of weeks, a pi pico is just shorted.

It is used on a board that gets a midi signal as input and controls six mosfets as output.
When powered by usb maximum power is drawn, the led stays off and the 2040 gets hot.
When powered by 12v it's the same except the AMS1117 also gets hot.
I measure a connection to ground between pin 35(3v3) and 36(ADC_VREF). But I don't know if that is cause or effect.

There are 4 more boards like this that are currently working. So I want to know what caused that issue to prevent it from happening to the remaining boards.

Here you can see the schematic:

[image]

Maybe you can tell that there is something obviously wrong with the circuit.

Comment: Hello and welcome ... can I ask what is on the other side of J1 and J2; and the part number of Q1-6?

Comment: J1 and J2 are connected to RGB Led strips. Q1-6: AO3400A

Comment: what happens if you disconnect everything from the Pi and power the Pi with a USB cable?

Comment: I wanted to test that too , but I don't have the tools to desolder it.